# regex comma separated delimiter

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I'm trying to split my column by comma delimiter. So the column has multiple values like; **139,239,338,323**. For some reason the following code will work for the first column but the rest of the columns come empty.

```
SELECT  
Regexp_extract(StringToParse,r'^(?:[^,\/]*,\/){0}([^,\/]*),\/?') as Word0,
Regexp_extract(StringToParse,r'^(?:[^,\/]*,\/){1}([^,\/]*),\/?') as Word1,
Regexp_extract(StringToParse,r'^(?:[^,\/]*,\/){2}([^,\/]*),\/?') as Word2,
Regexp_extract(StringToParse,r'^(?:[^,\/]*,\/){3}([^,\/]*),\/?') as Word3,
Regexp_extract(StringToParse,r'^(?:[^,\/]*,\/){4}([^,\/]*),\/?') as Word4,
Regexp_extract(StringToParse,r'^(?:[^,\/]*,\/){5}([^,\/]*),\/?') as Word5,
Regexp_extract(StringToParse,r'^(?:[^,\/]*,\/){6}([^,\/]*),\/?') as Word6,
Regexp_extract(StringToParse,r'^(?:[^,\/]*,\/){7}([^,\/]*),\/?') as Word7,
Regexp_extract(StringToParse,r'^(?:[^,\/]*,\/){8}([^,\/]*),\/?') as Word8,
Regexp_extract(StringToParse,r'^(?:[^,\/]*,\/){9}([^,\/]*),\/?') as Word9
FROM
(SELECT event_list AS StringToParse FROM `mytable.2017`)
```

Comment: well, what's with all the weird escaped forward slashes for one thing. makes the pattern unreadable.  what about matching the commas instead of the non-commas?  `(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  SPLIT(StringToParse)[SAFE_OFFSET (0)] AS Word0, 
  SPLIT(StringToParse)[SAFE_OFFSET (1)] AS Word1, 
  SPLIT(StringToParse)[SAFE_OFFSET (2)] AS Word2, 
  SPLIT(StringToParse)[SAFE_OFFSET (3)] AS Word3, 
  SPLIT(StringToParse)[SAFE_OFFSET (4)] AS Word4, 
  SPLIT(StringToParse)[SAFE_OFFSET (5)] AS Word5, 
  SPLIT(StringToParse)[SAFE_OFFSET (6)] AS Word6, 
  SPLIT(StringToParse)[SAFE_OFFSET (7)] AS Word7, 
  SPLIT(StringToParse)[SAFE_OFFSET (8)] AS Word8, 
  SPLIT(StringToParse)[SAFE_OFFSET (9)] AS Word9 
FROM 
  (SELECT event_list AS StringToParse FROM `mytable.2017`)
```

you can test / play with above using dummy data as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `mytable.2017` AS (
  SELECT '139,239,338,323' AS event_list UNION ALL
  SELECT '123,456,789,135'
)
SELECT 
  SPLIT(StringToParse)[SAFE_OFFSET (0)] AS Word0, 
  SPLIT(StringToParse)[SAFE_OFFSET (1)] AS Word1, 
  SPLIT(StringToParse)[SAFE_OFFSET (2)] AS Word2, 
  SPLIT(StringToParse)[SAFE_OFFSET (3)] AS Word3, 
  SPLIT(StringToParse)[SAFE_OFFSET (4)] AS Word4, 
  SPLIT(StringToParse)[SAFE_OFFSET (5)] AS Word5, 
  SPLIT(StringToParse)[SAFE_OFFSET (6)] AS Word6, 
  SPLIT(StringToParse)[SAFE_OFFSET (7)] AS Word7, 
  SPLIT(StringToParse)[SAFE_OFFSET (8)] AS Word8, 
  SPLIT(StringToParse)[SAFE_OFFSET (9)] AS Word9 
FROM 
  (SELECT event_list AS StringToParse FROM `mytable.2017`)
```

Meantime, if for some reason you have to use regular expressions in this query - try below

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT  
  REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(StringToParse, r'([^,\/]*),\/?')[SAFE_OFFSET(0)]  AS Word0,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(StringToParse, r'([^,\/]*),\/?')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)]  AS Word1,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(StringToParse, r'([^,\/]*),\/?')[SAFE_OFFSET(2)]  AS Word2,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(StringToParse, r'([^,\/]*),\/?')[SAFE_OFFSET(3)]  AS Word3,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(StringToParse, r'([^,\/]*),\/?')[SAFE_OFFSET(4)]  AS Word4,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(StringToParse, r'([^,\/]*),\/?')[SAFE_OFFSET(5)]  AS Word5,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(StringToParse, r'([^,\/]*),\/?')[SAFE_OFFSET(6)]  AS Word6,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(StringToParse, r'([^,\/]*),\/?')[SAFE_OFFSET(7)]  AS Word7,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(StringToParse, r'([^,\/]*),\/?')[SAFE_OFFSET(8)]  AS Word8,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(StringToParse, r'([^,\/]*),\/?')[SAFE_OFFSET(9)]  AS Word9
FROM
  (SELECT event_list AS StringToParse FROM `mytable.2017`)
```

Of course, in all above examples you can simplify code by introducing subquery for SPLIT of REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL and then just select each array's element in outer select

Comment: Dangit, you beat me to it ha ha. It takes too long to type from my phone :) I'll leave my answer up since it may be faster to compute the array just once depending on the size of the strings and number of rows.

Comment: Sure. You are the best anyway and I am your biggest fan! :o) and definitelly typing on laptop is faster than in phone :o)

Comment: @ElliottBrossard with Mikhail around, it's hard to get an answer up in time! He usually beats everyone to it. I tend to just pick up the scraps left behind :) Mikhail - do you have some sort of notification set up for new questions on BigQuery?!

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the SPLIT function instead. For example,

```
SELECT
  parts[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] AS Word0,
  parts[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] AS Word1,
  parts[SAFE_OFFSET(2)] AS Word2,
  parts[SAFE_OFFSET(3)] AS Word3,
  parts[SAFE_OFFSET(4)] AS Word4,
  parts[SAFE_OFFSET(5)] AS Word5,
  parts[SAFE_OFFSET(6)] AS Word6,
  parts[SAFE_OFFSET(7)] AS Word7,
  parts[SAFE_OFFSET(8)] AS Word8,
  parts[SAFE_OFFSET(9)] AS Word9
FROM (
  SELECT SPLIT(event_list, ',') AS parts
  FROM `mytable.2017`
);
```